# Java Split take individual words out out and save them as Strings?

Tags: java, string, split

Ok, so basically, say I have the following code, so I split up the time. But I want to take the individual data from the split and store them into the variables. So like, I split the data, and so far I just print it out split up, but what I want to do is like print out

Hour 15
Minute 42
Second 13

If that makes any sense. Is this possible to do? Thanks.

```
public class task2 {
    public static void main(String[] args){


        String hour;
                String minute;
                String second;

        String dateTime = "15:42:13";

        String array [] = dateTime.split(" ");
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
            System.out.println(array[i]);
        }

                //Set individual data into variables and them print out

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible. What you have to do is, split with `:`

```
String array [] = dateTime.split(":");
```

That gives

```
15
42
13
```

Then you can assign like, without for loop

```
 String hour   = array[0];
 String minute = array[1];
 String second = array[2];
```

Comment: Oh of course, in an array each data has it's own index if I remember correctly. I'mma try this now, thanks a lot! :)

Comment: @DanielSpeed If you use loop then it requires the if conditions to check what is what :)

Answer (score 1):

```
public class task2 {
public static void main(String[] args){


    String hour;
            String minute;
            String second;

    String dateTime = "15:42:13";
    String array [] = dateTime.split(":");
    hour=array[0];
minute=array[1];second=array[2];
    System.out.print("Hour "+hour);System.out.print(" ");    System.out.print("Minute "+minute);System.out.print(" ");
    System.out.print("Second "+second);


            //Set individual data into variables and them print out

}
}
```

**output**
Hour 15 Minute 42 Second 13

Answer (score 1):

It should be `String array [] = dateTime.split(":");`

Comment: Yeah, sorry missed that out. I copied some code where I was just spliting the time and date up by a white space and forgot to change the split. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public class task2 {
public static void main(String[] args){



    String dateTime = "15:42:13";

    String array [] = dateTime.split(":");

    //Set individual data into variables and them print out
    String hour   = array[0];
    String minute = array[1];
    String second = array[2];




}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class task2 {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String dateTime = "15:42:13";
        String array [] = dateTime.split(":");
        String hour = array[0];
        String minute = array[1];
        String second = array[2];

    //...

}
```

}